# How to write a query procedure that can be send to other local machines?(Beginner)

Tags: sql, ssms-2017

I have the database, tables, PK's and FK's, i need to send it to the other local machine, i tried writing some query's but it failed. 
(Please be polite, just started :) )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Search around for  "Generate scripts". Run produced code on target machine.

Comment: Also when asking a question it helps to add your script here too

Comment: Yes i tried that too, but i need to write it in a query, the whole database(or a certain table) :)

Comment: Oh, ok, i'll keep that in mind :0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be more clear on your actual goal, the question is very vague. If you are trying to transfer data from one data base to another database, which is what I assume you mean, I would highly recommend using SQL server Integration Services. You create SSIS packages in Visual Studio and it will allow you to write simple queries from your data source and insert them into the tables of the destination database. You will need to download Visual Studio and install the integration services add on. Hope this helps.